# Vue Js 3: Use Prop default value as Template String

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am currently building an app with PrimeVue.
There is a given component (not a vue one, a framework component of PrimeVue) where I can use give a title by using the "**legend**" property of a **FieldSet** Component. I have defined a prop called "**HeaderTitle**" with a default, I want to use the value of "**HeaderTitle**" for the "**legend**" property of the given component.

given

```
 <Fieldset
        legend="title"
        :toggleable="true"
        :collapsed="true"
        @click="initalMethod"
    >
```

full component

```
<template>
    <Fieldset
        legend="title"
        :toggleable="true"
        :collapsed="true"
        @click="initalMethod"
    >
        <Fieldset legend="Fallmanager" :toggleable="true" :collapsed="true">
            <div class="p-d-flex p-jc-between">
                <h3>Basic</h3>
                <InputSwitch v-model="checked1" />
            </div>
            <div class="p-d-flex p-jc-between">
                <h3>Basic</h3>
                <InputSwitch v-model="checked2" />
            </div>
            <div class="p-d-flex p-jc-between">
                <h3>Basic</h3>
                <InputSwitch v-model="checked1" />
            </div>
            <div class="p-d-flex p-jc-between">
                <h3>Basic</h3>
                <InputSwitch v-model="checked1" />
            </div>
            <div class="p-d-flex p-jc-between">
                <h3>Basic</h3>
                <InputSwitch v-model="checked2" />
            </div>
        </Fieldset>
        <br />
        <Fieldset legend="Reserverechner" :toggleable="true" :collapsed="true">
            <div class="p-d-flex p-jc-between">
                <h3>Basic</h3>
                <InputSwitch v-model="checked1" />
            </div>
            <div class="p-d-flex p-jc-between">
                <h3>Basic</h3>
                <InputSwitch v-model="checked2" />
            </div>
            <div class="p-d-flex p-jc-between">
                <h3>Basic</h3>
                <InputSwitch v-model="checked1" />
            </div>
            <div class="p-d-flex p-jc-between">
                <h3>Basic</h3>
                <InputSwitch v-model="checked1" />
            </div>
            <div class="p-d-flex p-jc-between">
                <h3>Basic</h3>
                <InputSwitch v-model="checked2" />
            </div>
        </Fieldset>
        <br />

        <Fieldset legend="MedInfo" :toggleable="true" :collapsed="true">
            <div class="p-d-flex p-jc-between">
                <h3>Basic</h3>
                <InputSwitch v-model="checked1" />
            </div>
            <div class="p-d-flex p-jc-between">
                <h3>Basic</h3>
                <InputSwitch v-model="checked2" />
            </div>
            <div class="p-d-flex p-jc-between">
                <h3>Basic</h3>
                <InputSwitch v-model="checked1" />
            </div>
            <div class="p-d-flex p-jc-between">
                <h3>Basic</h3>
                <InputSwitch v-model="checked1" />
            </div>
            <div class="p-d-flex p-jc-between">
                <h3>Basic</h3>
                <InputSwitch v-model="checked2" />
            </div>
        </Fieldset>
        <br />
    </Fieldset>
</template>

<script>
import Fieldset from 'primevue/fieldset';
import InputSwitch from 'primevue/inputswitch';
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

const TogglebarCards = defineComponent({
    name: 'TogglebarCards',
    emits: ['initialMethod'],
    components: {
        Fieldset,
        InputSwitch,
    },
    props: {
        HeaderTitle: {
            type: String,
            default: 'Cockpit',
        },
    },
    setup() {
        const checked1 = ref(false);
        const checked2 = ref(true);

        return { checked1, checked2 };
    },
    data() {
        return {
            title: '',
            description: '',
        };
    },
    methods: {
        initalMethod() {
            this.$emit('initialMethod', this.$data);
        },
    },
});
export default TogglebarCards;
</script>

<style></style>
```

Something like `legend="{{HeaderTitle}}". This one didn't work. Currently it's just displaying the string given inside the legend tag.

[image: title]

Comment: `:legend="HeaderTitle"` ?

Comment: Sorry, this works! Nice

Answer (score 0):

Bind the `HeaderTitle` on the component, aswell as passing the `legend` prop.

```
<Fieldset
    :legend="whatever.title"
    :HeaderTitle="whatever.title" // if you still need it
    :toggleable="true"
    :collapsed="true"
    @click="initalMethod"
>
```